Straight-line program for sets
Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a collection of sets. A set straight-line program that enumerates $\mathcal{S}$ is a sequence of sets $B_1,\ldots,B_m$, such that

$\mathcal{S}\subseteq \{B_1,\ldots,B_m\}$.
For each $i$, either $|B_i|=1$ or $B_i = B_j\cup B_k$ for some $j,k<i$.

Have this kind of problem been studied before?

I haven't seen this exactly before, but people have studied circuits over sets of natural numbers, where the operations are $\cap,\cup,+,\times$ and complement,  and each gate computes a set of natural numbers. Seems pretty related. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuits_over_sets_of_natural_numbers and refs therein.

ZDD can be seen as a restricted form of what you want to do (without unions and with an underlying order the elements should go in); OBDD too but the semantics is a bit farther from what you ask. With union, that would give non deterministic OBDD; I do not know whether non det ZDD have been introduced in the literature but that would not be too hard to define (just add $\vee$-gates corresponding to unions). That would give you interesting properties: you can compute size of the set computed by a ZDD, or approximate it with an FPRAS in the non-deterministic case, uniformly sample elements etc.

This problem is basically equivalent to the minimum AND-circuit problem.
They ask for a minimum circuit that only use AND gates, and it tries to compute a set of monomials. A monomial is computed by the circuit if one of the output of some gate is such monomial.
Arpe, Jan; Manthey, Bodo, Approximability of minimum AND-circuits, Algorithmica 53, No. 3, 337-357 (2009). ZBL1172.68061.
